# C# Как в Reflection выбрать метод, возвращающий Expression и применить его

Tags: c#, expressions

Делаю фильтры для грида.
В пользовательском классе есть метод, который возвращает преднастроенный Expression для зависимости одного свойства от ввода пользователем строкового значения:

```
public static Expression<Func<NPOModel, bool>> movement(string value)
{
    return p =>
     (
         (p.movement == "+")
            ? "поступление на счет"
            : "списание со счета"
     ).Substring(0, value.Length).ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower()
  );
}
```

Далее, в коде метода `Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFilter(string propertyName, object propertyValue)`, формирующем фильтры для `LinqToSql` мне необходимо выбрать значение этого метода и сформировать из него lambda.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Точно также, как и любой другой метод. Для простоты положим, что переданный метод расположен в классе `Filters`:

```
internal class Filters
{
    public static Expression<Func<NPOModel, bool>> movement(string value)
    {
        return p =>
         (
             (p.movement == "+")
                ? "поступление на счет"
                : "списание со счета"
         ).Substring(0, value.Length).ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Класс NPOModel, будем считать, содержит одно свойство `movement`

```
internal class NPOModel
{
    public string movement { get; set; }
}
```

Если я правильно понимаю задачу, то в коде метода `Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFilter(string propertyName, object propertyValue)` `propertyName` - это имя проеряемого свойства, которое совпадает с именем метода, предоставляющего `Expression`, а `propertyValue` - значение, передаваемое в метод, предоставляющий `Expression`. Тогда метод может выглядеть так:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFilter<T>(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    var method = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetType(typeof(Filters).FullName)
        .GetMethod(propertyName);

    var expression =
        (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)method.Invoke(
            null,
            BindingFlags.Default,
            null,
            new object[] {propertyValue},
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    return p => expression.Compile()(p);
}
```

Замечу, что вызов метода, возвращающего `Expression`, не отличается от вызова любого другого метода через рефлексию. Контрольный пример:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var expression = GetFilter<NPOModel>("movement", "поступление");
    var func = expression.Compile();
    Console.WriteLine(func(new NPOModel { movement = "+" }));
    Console.WriteLine(func(new NPOModel { movement = "-" }));
}
```

Он пишет `True` для первого вызова функции и `False` для второго, что, в целом, логично.